# Python - Overloading of a method (with operator oveloading) for varying # arguments?

Tags: operator-overloading, static-methods, class-method

As a newbie to object oriented, I'm practicing class using this:

```
import numpy as np    

class complex():

    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2 = None):
        self.real = arg1
        if arg2 == None:
            self.imag = 0
        else:
            self.imag = arg2            
        self.num = np.complex(self.real, self.imag)               

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if np.iscomplex(other):
            return np.multiply(self.numb, other.num)
        else:
            return np.multiply(self.num, other)

    def __str__(self): 
        return "Foo"

def test():        
    a = complex(3)
    b = complex(1, 5)        
    print(a * b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

I'm trying to overload the operator `*` simultaneously oveloading the class method `__mul__` since I got different permutations of arguments passing in. The above code can do `(object, object)` or `(object, 'int')`.

**How to pass `self` as the second argument something like `('int', object)`?**

Things I tried from my basic understanding: *(correct me if I'm wrong)*

1. Static method with `self` as second argument, but inbuilt operators cannot be overloaded in a static method.
2. Overloading the method `__mul__`, but not sure on a good-pratice/right-way to force `self` as second argument.

Appreciate any help in advance. Please comment below if you need more info.

Comment: Python does not support overloading, there can only be one method of a given name per class. Use a conditional inside your method, just like your code shows.

Comment: Any tip on condtional statement for passing `self` as second argument?

Comment: Oh, overlooked that part of the question. See [object model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__) in docs: for `x * y`, if `x.__mul__` is not implemented, then `y.__rmul__` is executed. Thus, to process `4 * complex(1, 2)`, make `def __rmul__(self, other)` on your class; `other` will be `4` in this example.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks, that should help!